# Why do I edit the CSS in ASP.NET Core MVC, the layout does not get the newly edited CSS, but only the CSS of the original template

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it because the template gets the CSS late, because after a while the layout in that template gets the CSS.

I tried with the inline style, and it automatically produced the desired result. But with external style, it is not like that.

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?